# Elaboration of a paragraph in Hatcher.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The paragraph is given below:

> [image]

My questions are:

1- Why the deformation retraction is a nonsymmetric notion while the homotopy equivalence is a symmetric one? symmetric and nonsymmetric with respect to what?

2-why we are sure that non of those 3 graphs is a deformation retract of any other?

Thanks!

Comment: (2) I'd say none of them is a subset of another.

Comment: (1) Likewise, the whole space $X$ may (deformation-)retract to some $A\subseteq X$, but $A$ itself won't (deformation-)retract to $X$ because $X\nsubseteq A$.

Comment: @Gae.S. those are actually the answers.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gae.S.

Comment: Your asking "symmetric and nonsymmetric with respect to what" suggests to me that you are not sufficiently familiar with the relevant notion of a symmetric relation. That notion doesn't involve any "with respect to". A relation $R$ is called symmetric if whenever $xRy$ then also $yRx$.

Answer (score 2):

A detail you probably missed is that "retract to something (by deformation or otherwise)" is a relation between a space $X$ and *a subspace* of it $A$. Therefore it is inherently asymmetric (because when $A\subseteq X$, $X\nsubseteq A$ unless $X=A$) and it doesn't hold between generic random spaces such as the three you mention. Those three spaces do not satisfy any mutual inclusion that I can see.